# gradient background on radar chartjs

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

I've got a radar chartJs.

I cant figure out how to put inside the area a radial gradient.
When putting the current code, it only takes 1 color as background-color by default

current code:

```
let ctx = document.getElementById('chart-0').getContext("2d");
let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0.000, 150.000, 300.000, 150.000);

// Add colors
gradient.addColorStop(0.035, 'rgba(234, 25, 78, 1.000)');
gradient.addColorStop(0.225, 'rgba(0, 8, 249, 1.000)');
gradient.addColorStop(0.983, 'rgba(42, 255, 0, 1.000)');

let data = {
    backgroundColor: gradient,
    labels: labelData,
    datasets: [{
        borderColor: presets.red,
        data: [20,20,20,20,20],
        label: labeldata
    }]
};
const options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    spanGaps: false,
    scale: {
        pointLabels: {
            fontSize: 14
        }
    },
    elements: {
        line: {
            tension: 0.000001
        }
    },
    legend: {
        labels: {
            fontSize: 16
        }
    }
};

 chart = new Chart('chart-0', {
    type: 'radar',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

Comment: still no solution @AtarC5?

Answer (score 0):

Each dataset also should include `backgroundColor` property with assigned gradient values. I've created [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smdegqp8/1/) based on your code.

Comment: Thanks for answering! but, i'm trying to achieve a single dataset with a radial centered gradient on it, is it possible?